# How did they get this result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please, explain these computations:

1) $-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 +1 =  \cos^2x$

$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  =  \cos x$

How did we get  $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$   from   $-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 +1$?

2) $-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 +1 = \cos^2x$

$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \cos x$

How did we get $ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$   from  $-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 +1 $?

Comment: For 1, note that $-(1/2)^2+1=3/4$ and so the square root of it is $\sqrt{3}/2$.

Comment: @DrStrangeLove I fixed the formatting using \LaTeX; is everything how you originally intended it to look?

Comment: @chris Thanks! It's OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

1. $$\cos^2 x = -(\frac{1}{2})^2 + 1$$

   $$\cos^2 x = -\frac{1}{4} + 1=\frac{3}{4}$$

   Which is:

   $$\sqrt \cos^2 x = \sqrt \frac{3}{4}$$

   $$\cos x = \pm \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

Same works for the second one.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:

$$ \cos^2(x) = 1 - (\frac{1}{2})^2 $$  and

$$ \cos^2(x) = 1 - \sin^2(x) $$ so immediately we have

$$ \sin(x) = \pm\frac{1}{2} $$  then, since $\sin(x) = \frac{opp}{hyp}$ we have from the reference triangle,  $$ \cos(x) = \frac{adj}{hyp} = \pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$ and also
$$ \tan(x) = \frac{opp}{adj} =\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{-\left(\frac12\right)^2 +1} = \sqrt{-\frac14 +1} = \sqrt{\frac34} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 +1} = \sqrt{-\frac24 +1} = \sqrt{\frac24} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

though you should also consider the negative square roots.